# Oracle 11g - Is it possible to determine update or insert in a function / procedure?

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g, case, procedure

I am working with Oracle 11g and I got a question.

What I want to do is :

- make a procedure
- when this procedure has called, it will move data form one table to the other (column is almost same, but has different primary key)
- Since, they do not use same field as PK, it occurs an error if use insert statement only.
- So I want to do if table has a key than update, otherwise insert.

i.e. DDL like follow. It has almost same, but pk.

```
create table Tbl_A (
  a_pk number constraints pk_tbl_a primary key
  , b_pk number
  , some_text varchar2(10)
  , created date
  , changed date
);

create table Tbl_B (
  a_pk number
  , b_pk number constraints pk_tbl_b primary key
  , some_text varchar2(10)
  , created date
  , changed date
);
```

Psuedo of what I want :

```
create or replace procedure mv_data
is 
begin
 case when [if Tbl_B has same b_pk] then [update statement] end
 else [create statement] end;
commit;
end;
```

- I know I can not use `case when` like above, but that what I am trying to achieve is something like that. `MyBatis` could be a solution, but the client want to this with only DB.(Actually, this job will be executed by Oracle `DBMS_SCHEDULE`)

Thanks for your kind answers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use MERGE

Some references:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement

http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the MERGE solution as suggested by valentin you can use the following construction:

```
begin
    -- try the insert
   insert...
exception
  when dup_val_on_index 
  then
     update...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :D. Even though I solved mine with `merge into`, but this also be a great tip for people like me bb